# Separate images for separate versions

Tags: iphone, image, ios4

My client said to me that i have to use different images for iPhone 4 (retina display) and different for other older versions

How to do this can anyone help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On iOS, you can have two pictures for the same place.

```
myPicture.png // normal size
myPicture@2x.png // double size
```

The device will automatically switch to the correct picture based on the screen resolution.

If you should use totally different picture, you can detect device by this way [Detect Retina Display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504173/detect-retina-display)

Answer (score 4):

1. [How to design for retina display?](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/17/designing-for-iphone-4-retina-display-techniques-and-workflow/)

Basically you will have 2 sets of images. File1.png and File1@2x.png. Rest is taken care by the os depending on the device.

Answer (score 3):

See [Specifying High-Resolution Images in iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/ImageSoundResources/ImageSoundResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH7-SW17) for a complete description of how to do this. In a nutshell, you provide the usual images, and then high resolution versions with the same name plus "@2x".