# Knowing device type -- Retina/non-Retina

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect Retina Display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504173/detect-retina-display)

How can we know if a device has a retina display or not from objective C code?

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: Same as [Detect Retina Display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504173/detect-retina-display)

Comment: What has the time zone got to do with Retina display?

Answer (score 56):

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]
    && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] >= 2.0) {
    // Retina
} else {
    // Not Retina
}
```

Comment: This should probably be >= 2.0 now (iPhone 6/6+)

Answer (score 5):

You can check the `scale` property on `[UIScreen mainScreen]` if it is 2.0 you are running on retina, if it is 1.0 you are not. You can also get the scale from the current CoreGraphics Context.

Comment: And the application will crash if the user runs it on iOS < 4

Comment: Correct. This is why you want to check first if [[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] is true. This is the general concept of how you would code to ensure backwards compatibility.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can determine that directly. You'll have to infer it from the model information you can get back from sysctlbyname (see the iOS man pages). For example:

```
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
char *machine = malloc(size);
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
```

will give you back a string like "iPhone3,1" which has a retina display, or "iPhone 2,1" which hasn't.

Comment: This is a terrible idea—it's not future-proof at all, and doesn't even account  for the fourth-gen iPod touch, which also has a Retina display. The `UIScreen` class's `scale` property, as described in the other answers, is the correct way to do this.

Comment: Good point. I stand corrected.