# My app got rejected and was wondering why exactly?

Tags: iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

- was not optimized to support the device screen size and/or resolution

I made my app for the iPhone and got rejected due to this. But my app fits perfectly with iPhone. Is there something I am missing? I don't think this app is universal at all because the binary says ipodtouch/iphone family.

Comment: Does your app support both retina and non-retina devices?

Comment: Did you add images which support all iPhone devices(3g,3gs,4S)?

Comment: How do I check if my app have retina display.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504173/detect-retina-display

Comment: If my app works on ipodtouch 4g does it mean it has retina display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common cause of this problem is that you haven't properly supported different device resolutions. You need to make sure that all your images are optimized for both retina and non-retina devices, not just for your icons and splash image.

For example, an iPhone 3GS has a screen resolution of 320x480 so a background image may be 320x480, but the retina iPhones have a screen resolution of 640x960 so you need to have an "@2x" version of the image for these devices.

This means that your app must contain `myBackgroundImage.png` and `myBackgroundImage@2x.png`.

Additionally, just because your images are retina compliant doesn't mean that is all you have to do. If you started with a 320x480 image and scaled it up to 640x960 slapped an @2x on it and called it retina you will be rejected. Make sure all of your graphics are the proper resolution, and are not distorted in any way.

Comment: What if he had restricted the app for just retina devices - iPhone 4 and iPhone 4S. Would that still get rejections without the non @2x files? just wondering

Comment: @KaanDedeoglu that's a good point. I'm honestly not sure how you're supposed to handler that.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a number of reasons for this:

- Do you have both 57x57 and 114x114 pixel icons? (the 114x114 is for retina)
- Do you have both a Default.png **and** a Default@2x.png for the retina display?
- If you have images in your app, have you set them up as follows, so that they appear sharp on the retina display?:
  `img.frame = CGRectMake(img.center.x, img.center.y, img.frame.size.width/2, img.frame.size.height/2);`

Comment: It isn't my app icons, because they sent me a screenshot of main screen. The only other thing they added was this.- included poor quality images and/or hard to read typography. And I believe that is bs. Also they said it would be important to refine menu option and images in your app. I can show you the screenshot if you would like?