# how to make resizable image with @2x file?

Tags: ios, resizable

My code:

```
self.commentTextViewBorder.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"border_comment_field"]
resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(11, 11, 11, 11)];
```

I found it did not user @2x image file to make resiable. Is it any problem?

Comment: Just put one condition regarding the retina display and accordingly use the @2x image for making the resized image as I know you have to do it in coding :)

Comment: if device has non-ratina display use simple image like above shown in post and if it is ratina use `@"border_comment_field@2x"` instead of `@"border_comment_field"`. That's it. For determined which display device have, there is lots of posts on SO just try to search with `how to find ratina display device through coding`

Comment: @Wolvorin do you means I just make a 2x image file in resource and do not need modify code, ios can make things do right?

Comment: just try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4641481/1132951) out

Comment: @ZhouQi He doesn't say that, but it's true anyway. You don't need to change the code, `UIImage` automagically knows which image file to choose. If the app is run on a retina device, then it will choose the `@2x` image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your `image_name.png` & `image_name@2x.png` at your main bundle folder, and just use

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name.png"];
```

is fine. The correct one will be used automatically depend on the devices w/ or w/o retina display.

Comment: yes, you're right, but use @2x file UIEdgeInsetsMake(11, 11, 11, 11) should be UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5)