# Render part of MKMapView to image

Tags: ios, mkmapview, uipopovercontroller, mapkit

I am interested in capturing a portion of the map to create the image you see on the top of the popover. I guess I'll capture a UIImage, you can do so starting from the coordinates of the pin?

Thanks

[image: Apple maps popover]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On `iOS7` you can use `MKMapSnapshotter`

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like this:

```
- (UIImage*) imageFromView:(UIView*)view rect:(CGRect)rect {
    // capture the full view in an image
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);

    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage* viewImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // crop down to just our desired rectangle, accounting for Retina scale 
    CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    CGRect scaledRect = CGRectMake(scale * rect.origin.x, scale * rect.origin.y,
                                   scale * rect.size.width, scale * rect.size.height);
    CGImageRef resultImgRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([viewImg CGImage], scaledRect);
    UIImage* result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: resultImgRef
                                          scale: 1.0f / scale
                                    orientation: UIImageOrientationUp];

    CGImageRelease(resultImgRef);
    return result;
}

- (IBAction)onButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    // just pick the map's center as the location to capture.  could be anything.
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = self.map.centerCoordinate;
    // convert geo coordinates to screen (view) coordinates
    CGPoint point = [self.map convertCoordinate:center toPointToView: self.map];

    // make this span whatever you want - I use 120x80 points
    float width = 120.0;
    float height = 80.0;
    // here's the frame in which we'll capture the underlying map
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(point.x - width / 2.0,
                              point.y - height / 2.0,
                              width, height);

    // just show the captured image in a UIImageView overlay 
    //  in the top, left corner, with 1:1 scale
    UIImageView* overlay = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [self imageFromView: self.map rect: frame]];
    frame.origin = CGPointZero;
    overlay.frame = frame;
    [self.view addSubview: overlay];
}
```

The `imageFromView:rect:` method just captures a given rectangular area, within a given view, and produces a `UIImage`.

The `onButtonTapped` method uses the first method to capture an area around the *center* of my map, and display the captured image at the upper left corner of the screen.  Of course, you can replace the map **center** with the coordinate of your pin, make the area width/height whatever you like, and put the resulting image into your popup view.

This is just a demonstration.  I used a button in my sample app, just to trigger the capture, after panning the map where I wanted it to be.

### Results

[image]

### Limitations

My code just displays the captured rectangle at a 1:1 size ratio. Of course, if you want, you can put the captured `UIImage` into a `UIImageView` that scales it however you like.  You could make the image bigger.  But, you will lose image sharpness if you do that.  This process just does a screen capture of a `UIView`.  It doesn't work on map data directly, so when you blow it up (display the image at a larger size), the image doesn't sharpen as it does when you actually zoom in on a `MKMapView`.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that on a retina display, the overlay shows a double size image.

Comment: My solution was to check for a retina display using this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504173/detect-retina-display and then multiplying frame.size.width and height by 2 just before the crop.

Comment: @Jenni.b, many thanks! I updated my answer to fix the bug you found.