# Preprocessor directives for different types of screens in Objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, version, preprocessor-directive

I need to differentiate between the retina screens or normal screens in my app for iPhone, similar to this:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE_VERSION < 3

NSString *uniquePath = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"close.png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: uniquePath];

#endif

#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE_VERSION >= 4

NSString *uniquePath = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"close@2X.png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: uniquePath];

#endif
```

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294100/how-to-differentiate-between-iphone4-and-iphone-3

Answer (score 0):

No you don't. Not with UIImage, it does that for you.

Comment: UIImage definitely does that for bundled images.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with the preprocessor. You could define your own symbol but I'm not sure what you'd do then. Somehow tell Apple different versions of the app worked on different devices?

Better is to do it at run time. Look at the `UIScreen` `scale` property.

Of course, normally you don't need to do this, as the other answer says. Most UIKit functions will add the @2x for you. There are some corner cases where you need to know, which is when the `scale` property comes into play.

Comment: Good one, scale is perfect for this.

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessor directives are resolved at compile time. In your example, this means that the compiler will not decide between those blocks of code when it's running on an iphone, it will decide when you build your application. So unless you're building a different application for each platform, you'll have to determine this at runtime.

I'm sure there's a way to get which version of iOS/iPhone you're running on. Just do that when you initialize your app or whenever you need this code, and then use an if/else if there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this. First of all, preprocessor would not help to define Retina screen as they are defined at compile time. But anyway, you don't need it because of Apple convention. Simply having a "close.png" in your project will be enough

```
NSString *uniquePath = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"close.png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: uniquePath];
```

I think you just want this though

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"close.png"];
```

If close.png (and the double size close@2x.png) is in your project when you build it, the second sample is the one to use. Test it, you will see that a retina phone will display the @2x file

Comment: He's loading it from the Documents directory. It looks like an external resource not bundled in the app.

Comment: Yes, that's why I included the first code sample. But from his question (loading a "close.png" seems a UI file typically included on build), I wasn't sure he really got how resources are loaded on iOS, so I added the second sample just in case